# Streaming output from CMD console to VB ListBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to pass text from console to the `Listbox1` line by line so hidden console will stream its output to my ListBox. But I'm getting `Cross-thread operation not valid`

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim start_info As New ProcessStartInfo()

    start_info.FileName = ("cmd.exe")
    start_info.UseShellExecute = False
    start_info.CreateNoWindow = False
    start_info.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    start_info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    start_info.Arguments = ("ipconfig")

    Dim proc As New Process
    proc.StartInfo = start_info
    proc.Start()

    Dim std_out As System.IO.StreamReader
    std_out = proc.StandardOutput

    Do
        ListBox1.Items.Add(std_out.ReadLine)
    Loop While proc.HasExited = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DoWork` event of the `BackgroundWorker` runs in a different thread than the UI. You'll have to make sure the Items are being added in the UI thread. Use for example `Invoke` to accomplish this.

Change your `Do ... Loop While` to the following:

```
Do
    Dim line As String = std_out.ReadLine()
    ListBox1.Invoke(Sub() ListBox1.Items.Add(line))
Loop While proc.HasExited = False
```

More information also on MSDN:

- [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx)
- [`Control.Invoke` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke.aspx)